# Passing data between controller and view with strongly typed model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a little bit of a problem with communicate between the controller and a view.

**UploadFile** (Class):

```
    public class UploadFile
    {
        public string OrignialFilePath { get; set; }
        public string FilteredFilePath { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } 

        public UploadFile(string x, string y, string z)
        {
            OrignialFilePath = x;
            FilteredFilePath = y;
            Name = z;
        } 
    }
```

**Files** (Class):

```
 public class Files
{

    public List<UploadFile> list { get; set; }

    public Files()
    {
        list = new List<UploadFile>();
    }
}
```

**Controller:** (I get files with HTTP POST to this controller)

```
  Files fileList = new Files();
        foreach (var file in Files)
        {
            UploadFile fu = new UploadFile(file.x, file.y, file.z); 
            fileList.list.Add(fu);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Result");
```

**Result:** (Strongly-typed view)

```
@model IEnumerable<SelectorITSelectorIT.Models.Files>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Result";
}

<h2>SelectorIT - Result</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach ( var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.list  ?????
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

In the `foreach var item in model`

When i write `@item.list` i cant go to the files within some index of the list ( i have there UploadFile instance).

I need in the `foreach` statement : `foreach var item in model.list` but it doesn't let me, how can i do it?

My Main goal is to Simply display in a table details about each UploadFile in the list of the model("Files").

How can i do it ?

Comment: `I need in the foreach statement : foreach var item in model.list but it doesn't let me, how can i do it?` ...what? "It doesn't let me" is not particularly helpful. Tell us *why*.

Comment: Are you expecting `return RedirectToAction("Result");` to pass your model to the view? Because it won't, unless you actually pass your filelist to the action as well.

Comment: @Flater and how can i exactly to this ?

Comment: @Flater thanks you helped me a lot.
i did :
return View("~/Views/Home/Result.cshtml",fileList);

Comment: @Ron No problem :) One small thing though, if you use `View()`, you send your model straight to the view, if you use `RedirectToAction()`, it sends your model to the Controller method that will render a View. You can use either, it's just an FYI :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I you need to use the `.list` property that you defined in `Files` and you need to change your view model to simply

```
@model SelectorITSelectorIT.Models.Files

...

@foreach (var item in Model.list) {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
    </tr>
}
```

On the other hand, if you really want an IEnumerable of Files, you need to rewrite your loop similar to this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    foreach(var file in item.list)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@file.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

But based on your question, I'm thinking you really just want a model of `Files` since it already has the list of `UploadFiles` in it.

Answer (score 1):

You said "i cant go to the files within some index of the list"

You cannot Index a foreach loop, if you want to display a Particular range of Indexes you need to use a For Loop,

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.list.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.list[i].Name)   
}
```